# How to use a character from the font eurm10?

Tags: fonts, amsfonts

I found a symbol I wanted to use in the documentation of the [amsfonts package](https://ftp.eq.uc.pt/software/TeX/fonts/amsfonts/doc/amsfndoc.pdf), it's in Appendix D, font `eurm10`, symbol 1F. I wanted to use it with some command, sort of like `\newcommand{\xmark}{symbol here}`, but I don't know how I can do this. I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font), however, they use the symbol to replace another math symbol, which is not what I want, I want to use it in the middle of normal text.

Does anybody know how I could do this? I appreciate your help.

Comment: That’s more commonly called `\chi` or `\textchi`, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Call the suitable font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\xmark}{{\usefont{U}{eur}{m}{n}\symbol{"1F}}}

\begin{document}

This is the xmark: \xmark

\end{document}
```

[image]